# Valgrind messages : invalid file descriptor 1024 in syscall close()

Tags: c, profiling, valgrind

I got this message while testing my bin with valgrind :

```
==8454== Warning: invalid file descriptor 1024 in syscall close()
```

I open once and I close once. The function belows open() a file, gets the content, and then close() the file.

```
int             parse(t_struct *data)
{
  int           fd;
  char          *s;

  if ((fd = open(data->file, O_RDONLY)) == -1)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open\n");
      return (-1);
    }
  while ((s = gnl(fd)) != NULL)
    {
      if (list_add_elem_at_back(&data->list, s) == FALSE)
        {
          fprintf(stderr,"Cannot stock\n");
          return (-1);
        }
    }
  close(fd);
  return (0);
}
```

Where/What's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Use `ulimit -n` , it shows you maximum open files, I guess you don't close fd, in some of piece of code. Please track your code for every `fopen` , `socket` or `select` have to have `close`.

Answer (score 1):

```
 if (list_add_elem_at_back(&data->list, s) == FALSE)
    {
      fprintf(stderr,"Cannot stock\n");
      return (-1);
    }
```

I don't know if this is the cause of your problem, but it is a bug: if `list_add_elem_at_back()` fails, you exit `parse()` without closing the file.

Comment: Yes you're right, thank you. But it doesn't resolve my problem.